# How can I apply a function to a dataframe with repetitive index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Hello, I have the following dataframe with repetitive indices:**

```
    Vol
1   25
1   15
2   20
2   30
3   25
3   10
4   15
4   20
```

I want to find a way that I can apply a function to do the sum of values in 'vol' column per each group of two indices. example:

**1. take the first two indices using code:**

```
one = df.loc[1:2]
one
```

it outputs first two indices 1,1 and 2,2:

```
    Vol
1   25
1   15
2   20
2   30
```

then do the sum of numbers in the column using:

```
one.sum()

output: 90
```

***2. Repeat the process again but this time with index 2,2, and 3,3.***

```
two=df.loc[2:3]
b=two.sum()
b

output: 85
```

**3. Repeat the process again but this time with index 3,3 and 4,4**

```
three=df.loc[3:4]
c=three.sum()
c

output : 70
```

I then put the output values in a new dataframe as

```
      vol2
0      90
1      85
2      70
```

***As you can see, the method is very tedious especially with huge dataframes. Is there a way I can apply a function that runs through the dataframe as described above?***

Comment: look into `DataFrame.rolling`

Answer (score 2):

We need to `sum` the duplicate row first , the `rolling` `sum`

```
x.sum(level=0).rolling(2).sum().dropna()
Out[79]: 
    Vol
2  90.0
3  85.0
4  70.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this -

```
df.reset_index().set_axis(['index','Vol'], axis=1).groupby(['index'])['Vol'].sum().rolling(2).sum().dropna()
```

```
index
2    90.0
3    85.0
4    70.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a pure pandas way of doing this, but a little python can do the trick:

```
values = []
for x in range( df.index[0] , df.index[-1] ):
  value = df.loc[ x : x + 1 ].sum()
  values.append(value)

totals = pd.DataFrame( values )
print( totals )
```

If you are a fan of list comprehensions:

```
other = pd.DataFrame( [ df.loc[ x: x+ 1 ].sum() for x in range( df.index[0] , df.index[-1] ) ] )
print( other )
```

Both yield:

```
   vol
0   90 
1   85
2   70
```